# How to tell apollo codegen to look for the exact files for the queries

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

my project directory structure is like this:

```
- schema.graphql
- package.json
- packages
-- types
--- package.json
--- src
---- graphql-types
----- user.ts
----- generated
```

Now in here, `schema.graphql` contains the downloaded schema from `apollo client:download-schema`. `user.ts` contains my graphql query like this:

```js
export const CURRENT_USER = gql`
  query CurrentUser {
    currentUser {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;
```

Now the problem is, I need to generate the type definitions for this query and the apollo codegen command will only pick the file if I add the exact path to the file in code generation command like this:

I want to tell the generator to search for all the ts files in there. I tried the following but all failed:

```sh
yarn run apollo codegen:generate --target=typescript --tagName=gql --addTypename --includes=packages/types/src/graphql-types/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx,graphql} --localSchemaFile=schema.graphql --globalTypesFile=packages/types/src/graphql-types/generated/graphql-global-types.ts --outputFlat packages/types/src/graphql-types/generated/

yarn run apollo codegen:generate --target=typescript --tagName=gql --localSchemaFile=schema.graphql --addTypename --includes=packages/types/src/graphql-types/**/*.ts --globalTypesFile=packages/types/src/graphql-types/generated/graphql-global-types.ts --outputFlat packages/types/src/graphql-types/generated/

yarn run apollo codegen:generate --target=typescript --tagName=gql --localSchemaFile=schema.graphql --addTypename --includes=packages/types/src/graphql-types --globalTypesFile=packages/types/src/graphql-types/generated/graphql-global-types.ts --outputFlat packages/types/src/graphql-types/generated/
```

I always get one of two errors:

```
No operations or fragments found to generate code for.
```

or

```
zsh: no matches found: --includes=packages/types/src/graphql-types/**/*.ts
```

Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like I'm missing the quotes in the includes parameter. So the correct way is:

```
--includes='packages/types/src/graphql-types/*.ts'
```

Source: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling/issues/1367